# Batch script: Checking if VALID or INVALID input

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need an output to check if the inputted data on notepad if the group is valid or invalid. A group name will be considered valid if it contains the string "APP_FRA".

output needed:

> Invalid - DVA_UA_ZETAFAXFAXCLIENT_2014_01-T000
>
> Valid   - APP_FRA_WFL_PEL_CIM_DK_ICG_SEPA
>
> Valid   - APP_FRA_WFL_PEL_CIM_NO_ICG_SEPA
>
> Invalid - DVA_UA_THOMSNONESMRT_57_00-T000
>
> Invalid - XSP_XA_LIBREOFFICECFG_50_00

==========================================

Here's what I did:

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /F %%i in (File.txt) do (

    set "f1=%%i"
    if "%f1%"=="%f1:APP_FRA=%" (
    echo Valid - %%i
) else (

    echo Invalid - %%i
))
```

==========================================

I'm getting this output always:

> Invalid - DVA_UA_ZETAFAXFAXCLIENT_2014_01-T000
>
> Invalid - APP_FRA_WFL_PEL_CIM_DK_ICG_SEPA
>
> Invalid - APP_FRA_WFL_PEL_CIM_NO_ICG_SEPA
>
> Invalid - DVA_UA_THOMSNONESMRT_57_00-T000
>
> Invalid - XSP_XA_LIBREOFFICECFG_50_00

I would appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're creating a variable inside of a `for` loop, you actually want to *enable* delayed expansion, and then use the `!variable!` naming convention for the variables you create and interact with inside the loop.

Also, you current logic says that a string is considered valid if it does *not* contain the string `APP_FRA`, which is the opposite of what you asked for.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /F %%i in (File.txt) do (

    set "f1=%%i"
    if not "!f1!"=="!f1:APP_FRA=!" (
        echo Valid - %%i
    ) else (
        echo Invalid - %%i
    )
)
```